# Weka equivalent of sklearn's pipelines and feature-unions

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, weka, pipeline

I have used sklearn's [PipeLine and FeatureUnion](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/pipeline.html) in some of my projects and find it extremely useful. I was wondering if there is any WEKA equivalent for it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no. Details below.

In weka, there's KnowledgeFlow, but this is a GUI element (weka.gui.knowledgeflow).

What you can use instead is the [FilteredClassifier](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/meta/FilteredClassifier.html) which is a classifier that works on filtered data. If you want to use several filters before the classifier, you can use the [MultiFilter](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/MultiFilter.html) instead of a filter.

If you want more flexibility, you can wrap FilteredClassifier. You can create a field `List<Object> filters` and then apply these filters before applying the classifier (buildClassifier, classifyInstance) depending on which types of filters they are, for example AttributeSelection or Filter.